# How to add checkboxes to tree nodes in extjs4

Tags: checkbox, extjs4, treeview

i am working in extjs4. i have view with tree panel as-

```
Ext.define('Balaee.view.qb.qbquestion.tree1', {

    extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
    title: 'Simple Tree',
    width: 200,
    height: 150,
    alias : 'widget.tree1',
   //store: 'qb.qbquestioncomplexityStore',
    rootVisible: true,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

In controller i have created static store. And binded it to this view. Code is as-

```
 var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
            root: {
                expanded: true,
                children: [
                    { text: "detention", leaf: true },
                    { text: "homework", expanded: true, children: [
                        { text: "book report", leaf: true },
                        { text: "algebra", leaf: true}
                    ] },
                    { text: "buy lottery tickets", leaf: true }
                ]
            }
        });

     var bchart=Ext.create('Balaee.view.qb.qbquestion.tree1',{
         store:store

     });
     var comp=Ext.getCmp('QuestionView');
     comp.removeAll();
     comp.add(bchart);
```

its working correctly. its displaying tree panel view correctly. But how to add checkboxes to this tree nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `checked` property to your tree node data either `true` or `false`. Existence of this property will tell ExtJs to add checkbox for a node.

example definition of `children` nodes for your tree:

```
children: [
                    { text: "detention", leaf: true, checked: true },
                    { text: "homework", expanded: true, children: [
                        { text: "book report", leaf: true },
                        { text: "algebra", leaf: true, checked: false}
                    ] },
                    { text: "buy lottery tickets", leaf: true }
          ]
```